# Exchanging SAP table data with table in Microsoft Access in real-time, how to?

Tags: ms-access, sap-basis

I have table "YXY" in SAP which holds the data which I would like to read in Microsoft Access in real-time.

For example, table "YXY" which holds some transaction data contains 1.000 records and I would like to see that records in Microsoft Access also in real-time.

How can do this (perhaps some example?) and is there any way I could violate my Oracle license? I wouldn't like that to happen.

I hope someone can help me with this because it is very important to me.

Thank you.
Adi

Comment: Please define "real time". Instantaneous data exchange is not possible (citing Einstein and Heisenberg) - what kind of delay is acceptable?

Comment: It could be 15-30 minutes delay, I think that wouldn't be a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table in question contains only CLIKE fields, you could use the function module RFC_READ_TABLE, either as a web service in newer releases or as a traditional RFC call using VBA. If you google for RFC_READ_TABLE and Access, you'll find enough examples to get the idea - I haven't tried any of them, so I don't want to recommend a single one. For this, you will only need a SAP user, the Oracle license does not enter into the equation.

Comment: Thank you very much for helpful and direct answer. I will try one of the examples and let you know right away if it works out.

Best regards,
Adi

Comment: I kind of stuck right now, unfortunatly.. I have found and read many useful articles and also found similar topics on web BUT I really don't know where to start. All I know I must make some simple form in Microsoft Access which will read data from certain table in SAP. What I don't know is:

- how to make this first form,
- on which event should I set this code (on load form, on button click etc?),
- I can't find any simple example made in M. Access on web?

Any help is appreciated and many thanks in advance!
Adi

Comment: Adi, it sounds like you should grab a book on MS Access development first. I'd need one, too, so I won't be able to help you out there.